# removing highly overlapped bounding boxes faster in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bounding-box

I have a csv file and it contains information about bounding boxes of detected objects in a large image.

the data frame looks like follows

Image name/xmin/ymin/xmax/ymax/confidence

image1/50/100/90/112/.96

image1/12/500/23/551/.91

image1/77/221/122/287/.88

.

.

.

what I'm doing is to remove labels redundant labels.

My procedure is if there are two labels that intersect with IoU of more than 50%, then I remove the label with less confidence.

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
      boxA = [row['xmin'], row['ymin'], row['xmax'], row['ymax']]
      for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        boxB = [row2['xmin'], row2['ymin'], row2['xmax'], row2['ymax']]
          if (iou(boxA,boxB) >= 0.5 and row2['confidence'] < row['confidence']):
            df.drop(index2, inplace=True)
```

this works and produces the results I want but it it very slow (4 mins for 2400 labels).

Does someone have a way to speed this up?

Comment: I'd recommend NOT modifying your data table on every dropped label, but store the deletions in a list, and delete them at the end. FROM HIGHEST INDEX TO LOWEST, otherwise the positions will change as you delete other entries.    You also can start the inner loop at index+1 because you've already done the other compare, (commutative property) adding an else clause to the confidence comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be quicker, but in general replacing nested loops with something from itertools can help :

```
 from itertools import product

 for (index, row), (index2, row2) in product(df.iterrows(), repeat=2):
      boxA = [row['xmin'], row['ymin'], row['xmax'], row['ymax']]
      boxB = [row2['xmin'], row2['ymin'], row2['xmax'], row2['ymax']]
          if (iou(boxA,boxB) >= 0.5 and row2['confidence'] < row['confidence']):
            df.drop(index2, inplace=True)
```

The challenge of course is that you are modifying the data frame while looping through it which might be problematic - i don't know how that impacts df.iterrows()

If I knew pandas better I wouldn't be suprised if there was a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tony. But I keep getting the following error ------------------------------------------ ['KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-15-4b3eace5607c> in <module>() 171 boxB = [row2['xmin'], row2['ymin'], row2['xmax'], row2['ymax']] 172 if (iou(boxA,boxB) >= 0.5 and row2['confidence'] < row['confidence']): --> 173 df.drop(index2,axis=0, inplace=True) 174 print(len(df)) 175 #and row2['confidence'] < row['confidence'] KeyError: '[442] not found in axis']

Comment: probably because you are modifying the data frame as you loop through it  -and using the product(..) function with iterrows() might not be sensible. Modifying a structure while iterating through it is always a code smell.
As other have said there are well known algorithms for finding overlapping polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad, welcome! to StackOverflow.  You can speed up processing by changing the O(N**2) double loop to an O(NlogN) sweep line algorithm (see [How to compute the union polygon of two (or more) rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345887/how-to-compute-the-union-polygon-of-two-or-more-rectangles)).